# How to set a value for an entire column in Google App Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want the entire column of 1 to read Build1 and not anything else. I'm not sure how to set hard data and use the push method to set it.

Does anyone know how to set a var of data and then call it to all the cells in a column not a row. It is an unlimited number of cells so I cannot tell it a range, because the range is always changing and expanding.

```
var seventeen = "Build1";
```

`[Build1][][][]`
`[Build1][][][]`
`[Build1][][][]`
`[Build1][][][]`

How would I call this type of action? I would like to know how to put static data in columns, because I need more than 1 column to own a static value.

Need to put a value in to an entire column regardless of the size. I have tried making it a var and calling the var pushing the var, filling in the var. Nothing is working for this.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please show what you tried and add a brief description of you search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Sets Column One to V

```
function setColumn(v=5) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow()).setValue(v); 
}
```

If you listerally want it all the way down to the bottom of the sheet then change getLastRow() to getMaxRows()

Comment: It doesn't work. I've tried it on my sheet and it doesn't throw an error but it doesn't work to do what I want. :(

Comment: Did pass a value to it with v?

Comment: I assigned a default value so that it will run without supplying a parameter.